# How to setup qemu as a server with different subdomain on a host server?

Tags: linux, virtualization, subdomain, qemu

I am trying to solve a problem, with a Linux server work as host, while qemu guest will have another server intended for subdomain.

I tried to make the host to access the guest server. And I read that this can be done through bridge. But I am concerning that the bridge only works with the wired interface, because I wish to make the guest server accessed by any connection to the host server.

To simplify, I wish to setup my host server which contains the guest server as a subdomain, and the server can be accessed by other computers.

I have tried to use qemu with "redir" options, but it doesn't work with "-net user". I tried with redirection because I think I can use Apache to create the subdomain with different port.

Is there any solution?

(Besides that, I have a very poor knowledge about the networking especially bridge, tap, tun, and vlan.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is solved by bridging or using TAP for the virtual machine part.

Using TAP,

1. create the tap0.
2. bring up the tap0.
3. assign the IP to tap0.
4. setup the iptables and start the iptables service
5. run qemu with tap option.
6. assign an IP in guest so that route to the tap0 IP.

Another method is using the bridge,

1. create the bridge, br0
2. bring up the br0
3. assign the IP to br0
4. run qemu with bridge option. It will create tap by itself
5. assign an IP in guest so that route to the bridge IP.

These steps not yet allows the remote computer to access the guest server.